# Override fieldset disabled attribute

Tags: html, forms, fieldset

I have a complex form with many `<input>` elements, most of which I need to disable conditionally (via AngularJS to precise, but this question primarily targets the HTML aspect).

In order to avoid having to set a `disabled` attribute on every element, I place my inputs into a `<fieldset>` and set the `disabled` attribute once. This disables **all** contained inputs fields.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fieldsets</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset disabled="true">

      <input type="text" placeholder="first">
      <input type="text" placeholder="second">

      <!-- many, many more -->

      <!-- trying to override here -->
      <input type="text" placeholder="last" disabled="false">

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I need to make a few exceptions and keep some inputs **enabled** even though the surrounding `<fieldset>` is disabled. I tried overriding the attribute there by setting `disabled="false"`, but this does not work.

Is there any elegant way to override the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: Tried to associate the inputs with another "pseudo" form with the `form` attribute, but no success. Placing the inputs in an additional `<fieldset>` doesn't work either. Looks like there's no alternative than setting disabled status individually.